# Terminal not configured - not showing folder, no tab completion, etc

Tags: command-line, bash

I access via ssh (command line) a Linux machine and the user is not configured to do anything. Backspace does not work, there is no tab completion, the current folder does not appear in the terminal (just a `$` sign). There is also no bash history.

The Ubuntu version 12.04, and I only have ssh access to it, I cannot access its graphical interface. When I log in, it goes automatically to a Tomcat folder, but there is a home folder where I tried copying a properly configured `.bashrc` file with no success.

How can I add these functionalities to my terminal from command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try running `bash -` from the command line you may be in a basic shell by default. If this fixes it you can run to fix it permanently.

```
chsh -s /bin/bash yourusername
```

then login again.

Comment: bash - works, thanks!! The permanent fix didn't change anything though, but I definitely do not mind typing bash - every time I log in

Comment: You need to run `chsh -s /bin/bash yourusername` then login again after running it before you should notice the difference.

Comment: hehe I thought only opening a new terminal would do it. Indeed after I logged out completely and logged in again, it became permanent. Sorry to bother you with my stupidity! Thanks again!

Comment: Hey no worries, can you mark the answer as correct when you can please.

Comment: thankx mate. saved me tonns